# My Eclipse Installation has no Java options or connections

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a new "programmer," and I've created a couple of very basic programs and so much of the terminology is very new to me. I wish to create an executable program from eclipse that I can use outside of eclipse and give a couple of other people for a project, and all of the tutorials said that I needed to use Java to create a .Jar program. The problem is that my version of Eclipse doesn't seem to have any options for working with Java. When I export, there is no option to export to Java. I have no option to create a new Java project either. I don't know the correct terminology, but it seems that my version of Eclipse is not connected to Java. Did I mess up somewhere along the line when installing Eclipse? Was there an option I failed to check? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Eclipse has a variety of plugins for different languages - https://www.eclipse.org/ide/ Honestly your lack of understanding of the terminology means you should be going through tutorials/online course/books first before asking on StackOverflow. Use your favorite search engine to find something appropriate as asking for tutorials is considered to be Off-Topic for this site. Good luck.

Comment: There are different flavors of Eclipse which one did you choose?

Comment: Thank you so much, Morrison Chang for your answer! It helped me in a way that going through hours of searching through tutorials couldn't!